# Error creating MYSQL function to work out time diff

Tags: mysql

I am creating a function as part of a database project with a group at university. I want the function to return the fastest time a race was complete in and have tried the following code. I am getting an error as I think it is trying to return more than one value but cannot think of another way to do this. Any help is appreciated.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calc_race_winner(in_race_id INT)
RETURNS FLOAT(10)
BEGIN
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_result AS (
SELECT 
    (TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(ps_result.finish_time, ps_race.start_time)) / 60) AS finish_time_mins
    FROM ps_race
    INNER JOIN ps_result ON ps_race.race_id = ps_result.race_id
    );
SELECT *
    FROM temp_result
    WHERE ps_race.race_id = in_race_id
    ORDER BY finish_time_mins ASC LIMIT 1;
RETURN finish_time_mins;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a local variable to read finish time into it and return the same.

```
begin
  declare finish_time_calculated_in_mins int default 0;

  create temp.....

  ....

  select finish_time_mins 
    into finish_time_calculated_in_mins 
    from temp_result
   where ps_race.race_id = in_race_id
   order by finish_time_mins asc 
   limit 1;

  return finish_time_calculated_in_mins;
end;
```